# User management PHP

Tags: php, user-management

I wonder what is the best way to manage users in a home-structured CMS.
Important feature that needs to be include is obviously security.

I heard about [UserCake](http://usercake.com/docs.php) and it seems to be a fair idea.

The questions is: should I make it myself or should I use a user script already made?

Comment: Get something that's already written, since it will have been tested well already. Have you looked at Zend Framework or Symfony Components? They might have something you can use. (Btw, in general requests for library recommendations are o/t here, since they date too quickly to be of use in our Q&A format).

Comment: Advantages of DIY: You know, what you have. You know, what you dont have. You have full control of everything. Disadvantages of DIY: Reinventing the wheel. Huge effort... Go with something that's already written, is what I'd do

Comment: ALWAYS have a good research, and look how other people have done this! You'll save a lot of time and nerves by giving yourself a good overview over existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the library fits your need, use it.

If the library *almost* fits your need, consider cloning it and make the minor changes to it [and providing a pull request, if your additions are worth].

If desired feature is part of you business core [i.e. you want to make money out of it], consider rewriting it from scratch.

But for such a feature, I would go for an existing tool - Symfony does the same with [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) for example.